# Derived equivalence of triangulated categories

Tags: derived-categories

Assum that we have two abelian categories $A$ and $B$. We know that if $D^b(A)$ is equivalent to $D^b(B)$, then $A$ is not equivalent to $B$ in general.

My question is : What is the condition on these two abelian categories such that they will be equivalent?

Thank you!

Comment: Any equivalence between $A$ and $B$ gives an equivalence between their derived categories. I think you mean the converse: if the derived categories are equivalent then $A$ and $B$ need not be equivalent.

Comment: Oups, yes exactly!

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu. Do you know any reference on this question?

Comment: The main terms to look up are "derived Morita equivalence" and "tilting theory".  You can find a brief overview and some references on nlab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+Morita+equivalence.